# Как добавить webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

После такого запроса в терминале PhpStorm:

```
webpack ./src/index.js ./public/bundle.js
```

> "webpack" не является внутренней или внешней
>   командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Хотя `npm` работает нормально.

Comment: Вы установили webpack через npm install webpack? Если да то используйте node_modules/.bin/webpack .src/index.js ./public/bundle.js или добавте webpack в $PATH

Comment: на самом деле, мне просто следовало установить его глобально -g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня возникла такая же ошибка. На форумах советуют установить пакеты глобально либо прописать путь вручную. Что то, что другое похоже на костыли.

С помощью команды `npm install` можно просто переподключить все пакеты зависимостей в `package.json`. Мне это помогло, и всё работает как надо.

Для того, чтобы пакеты записывались в качестве зависимостей в `package.json`, их также нужно устанавливать с флагом `--save` или `--save-dev`.